# Sending Userid as a dynamic parameter in JHipster

Tags: angular, rest, spring-boot, jhipster

I created a new REST API to list courses according to user id.
I want to send user id as a dynamic parameter to navbar menu link. But i don't know how to take logged user's id in jhipster? Is it any related example or any idea?

Comment: where is your code?? update it to post to help further

Comment: If your referring to the backend than you can use on your rest class CoursesResource.java the `SecurityUtils` class which has method  `getCurrentUserLogin` and do smth like `userRepository.findOneByLogin(SecurityUtils.getCurrentUserLogin());`  or you can use a direct spring data jpa query on your CourseRepository like `@Query("select course from Course course where course.user.login = ?#{principal.username}")\n\t\tCourse findByUserIsCurrentUser();`. You can find a lot of examples like this on Github. For example the [21point](https://github.com/mraible/21-points) is a good start.